# character/datetime variable manipulation in r

Tags: r, datetime, tidyr

I have a variable that begins with a number and a dash, e.g. "1-" or "2-". These are all character vectors where these numbers and dashes are followed by a string of words, eg `x <- c("1-place a", "2-place b", "3-place c")`. I'm trying to set my NA to blank. But I think R believes these are improperly formatted times, and is failing to execute the `df[is.na(df)] <- ""` command.

Basically I get the following error when I run that command:

Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

How do I either change the vector to eliminate all the "#-" prefixes in front of the remaining characters to simply get, eg, `x <- c("place a", "place b", "place c")` or, better still, how do I get R to realize these are not improperly formatted times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `str(df$variable)` to verify if the column is being read as a date. If it is, convert it to a character `df$variable<-as.character(df$variable)`.

Here is an example with just a vector showing your problem.

```
x<-as.Date("1-place a","1-place b","1-place c",NA)
x[is.na(x)] <- ""
str(x)
```

This doesn't work and running `str` we see that it is not actually a character, which `x[is.na(x)] <- ""` needs it to be to work.

```
y<-as.character(x)
y[is.na(y)] <- ""
```

So we simply convert that column or vector in this case to a usable format, and it works.